# Why do we need to and from methods in SlackMessage in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, slack

If the channel the notification will be posted to is defined by `routeNotificationForSlack`, why do we need `to` method in `SlackMessage`, and how it works? I will not be able to post to many channels chaining multiple `to` methods anyway.

Same for `from`: I registered my app and gave it some name, and the messages are posted using this name, not the one I provided in `SlackMessage` `from` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't, they're optional. [Check the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#formatting-slack-notifications)

Comment: I mean, they won't work anyway since slack's webhook determines the channel. Is there any case I can use to() at all?

Comment: Slack's legacy API still supports sending a channel name with each method which is why I assume Laravel still has the 'to' option. I don't know if you can enable the legacy webhooks on apps that don't already have them though, so you may not be able to use it https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations